# Embedding a react app to run inside of Wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

Needing to render a react app inside of an existing Wordpress site.  Found this following website helpful: https://medium.com/@CodeCareerCoach/react-app-inside-a-wordpress-page-or-post-4c7d38181b3d

However after following the steps I am able to get the react app to render on a page but now I am needing to render the app while keeping the existing Wordpress header and footer.

I have already tried installing the following plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/embed-react-application/

Which still renders the app but not inside of the root div that I define on a page.  Here is a sample of the code I was using.

```html
<div id="root">
</div>

[reactapp id="root"
  js="/static/js/main.1234ef2e.js"
  css="/static/css/main.55b7b575.css"
]
```

What I was hoping is that this short code that is provided by the plugin would render my app inside of the div but that the Wordpress content would still be rendered around it.

For the motivated, you can follow the tutorial spinning up your own Wordpress site inside of something like MAMP, XAMMP etc., spin up a sample react app using the react cli, build the project and upload the build files inside of Wordpress file structure at the same level as `wp-content` following the instructions from the blog post and see if they can get it to work.

I know this is some dirty magic I am trying to perform here but any guidance on what might get this working would be great.

Here is my github repo:
https://github.com/mmcguff/risk-assessment-tool-react-app

Perhaps there is something I am doing wrong with how I am setting this up.

Comment: Is it possible that it works the other way around? I understand the reactapp id stands for the id of the element **into your react js** file that you want to display in the HTML view where you write the shortcode. Additionally, I'm not sure the shortcode will work if you add it directly on the source code. Rather than that, I would create a template, then create a new page in WP using the template, and add the shortcode as the body of the page.

Comment: Haven't really done anything with wordpress templates but I will be looking into this.  Basically I will be creating some sort of conditional logic to say that when I am on the page then to render the react app inside of a particular div.  By doing it this way then the other content from WP should render without being overwritten by the react app right?

Comment: If you create a template for it, you should not need to worry about that. You can create a copy of ```page.php``` and name it let's say ```page-reactview.php```. Inside, you'll add a ```/* Template name: Whatever you like */``` and from that moment, you'll be able to choose this custom template for your pages inside the CMS dashboard. In the template, you'll be still importing all elements you want from the original template (headers, footer...) but also adapt the HTML view so that ```the_content``` of the page (the shotcode that you will add in the CMS page body) will be place where you want.

Comment: If I do it this way then every time there is a change to header or footer in the theme, I will need to remember to add these changes in the react apps template correct?  Or will these automatically update?

Comment: They will get modified automatically, as you'll be importing them, for example using the WP default function ```get_header();``` which pulls the content of a ```header.php``` file in the root of your theme. Normally ```header.php``` is already configured to pull all the changes you make from the dashboard customization. Take a look at the ```page.php``` file of your theme, the one I suggested you to copy, and probably it uses all those resources that way already.